# Unable to retrieve value from lookup field

Tags: soql

I am trying to get values from my object which have Contact as Look up field. But when I am trying to get value of Fields from Contact Object using relation I am unable to get any result.

EX:

```
List<SponsorTracking__c> stObj = [SELECT Id, Contact__r.MailingCountry , Contact__r.LastName , 
Contact__r.Name , Contact__r.MailingState , Contact__r.MailingCity , Contact__r.Account.Name , 
Contact__r.Title , Contact__r.FirstName , Contact__r.Email  ,Contact__c,Account__c,CustomerInfo__c FROM 
SponsorTracking__c WHERE Contact__c IN : cnTset]
```

**stObj.get('Contact__r.Title') is not returning any value even no exception is being thrown.**

Contact__c is Lookup to Contact Object

I tried stObj.get('Contact__r') and the get('Title') on returned Object.

Please let me know what i am missing here to get Contact__r.Title value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are retrieving a reference to an SObject from an SObject of unknown type you need to use the (poorly documented) [getSObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObject) method:

```
List<SObject> sobs = ...;
for (SObject s : sobs) {
    SObject c = s.getSObject('Contact__r');
    String t = (String) c.get('Title');
    ...
}
```

But as mrBlaQ correctly points out in this case the SObject type is known to the compiler so a direct reference (rather than references keyed by strings) can be used:

```
List<SponsorTracking__c> sobs = ...;
for (SponsorTracking__c s : sobs) {
    String t = s.Contact__r.Title;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't see a need for getSObject here. Can't you just refer to
s.Contact__r.Title
Inside the for() ?

Comment: @mrBlaQ You are right as in this case the type SponsorTracking__c is known. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using stObj.get() properly here. 
get() on a List object only supports integers. 
You'd do something like stObj.get(0).Contact__r.Title; for the first record returned from that query. Or, use the iterative method described by Keith.